# Ошибка при смене картинки imageview

Tags: android, imageview

Главное активити состоит из фрагментов, в одном из которых (ImageFragmentActivity) имеется imageview. При клике по checkbox (из другого фрагмента), картинка изменяется. Загружается активити нормально (оба фрагмента загружаются), но при клике по checkbox приложение закрывается с ошибкой. Вот код:

```
CheckBox rombcheckbox;
rombcheckbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rombcheckBox);

в oncreate:

fm= getSupportFragmentManager();

mImageFragmentActivity = new ImageFragmentActivity();
fm.beginTransaction()
        .add (R.id.container, mImageFragmentActivity)
        .commit();


rombcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
            rombimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.panno_2_4);
        } else {
            rombimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.panno_3_5_ob);
        }
    }
});
```

выдает ошибку

```
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                 at com….MainActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:102)
```

ссылаясь на строку

```
rombimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.panno_2_4);
```

Comment: в коде не видно как вы работаете с rombimageView?
как вы его покдлючате в разметке?

Comment: rombimageView содержится в xml макете ImageFragmentActivity (R.layout.activity_image_fragment), класс ImageFragmentActivity расширяет класс Fragment, переопределяет onCreateView {return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_image_fragment, container, false)} Я попробовала добавить в xml макет mainactivity фрагмент R.layout.activity_image_fragment с помощью тега fragment, убрала динамическое добавление фрагмента из кода, и у меня все заработало. Видимо нельзя так напрямую обращаться к imageView, расположенном во фрагменте, который добавляется динамически. Я так понимаю свою проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы ищете вью в классе активити, а нужно в фрагменте.
Должно быть примерно так:

```
View container = inflater.inflate(...);
rombcheckbox = (CheckBox)container.findViewById(R.id.rombcheckBox);
return container;
```